# TabItem Selected not Working Properly

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a `TabControl` that contains three `TabItems`. I have a label on each `TabItem` so I can program the click event, it looks like this;

```
<TabItem.Header>
    <Label Content="People" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="14" MouseLeftButtonDown="TabItemClick"/>
</TabItem.Header>
```

I want to program the `TabItem` click so that something happens depending on which `TabItem` is selected, so I wrote something like this;

```
private void TabItemClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var privilegeService = new PrivilegeService();
    if (companyTabItem.IsSelected == true)
    {
        generateCompanyPrivilegesButton.IsEnabled = true;
        applyCompanyPrivilegesButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    else if (peopleTabItem.IsSelected == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("People Selected");
        generatePeoplePrivilegesButton.IsEnabled = false;
        applyPeoplePrivilegesButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    else if (contractTabItem.IsSelected == true)
    {
        generateContractsPrivilegesButton.IsEnabled = false;
        applyContractsPrivilegesButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

As you can see I added in a `MessageBox` for some testing purposes to see when a `TabItem` is selected. The `MessageBox` is only displayed however after I LEAVE the `peopleTabItem`, not when I click onto it. How can I change this so that I can program someting that happens when the `TabItem` is clicked AND when it is selected too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use a different approach. Yo ucan use TabControl void SelectionChanged event of yout TabControl like this:

XAML:

```
<TabControl x:Name="testTab" SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
```

Code behind:

```
void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // you can use testTab.SelectedItem here or youtTab.IsSelected
}
```